# Why am I getting this error in Swan-Cygwin?

Tags: bash, shell, windows, cygwin

I am using [Swan](http://www.starlig.ht) for providing Linux support on my windows computer,

I am having a slight problem while opening "Swan Terminal" (Xfce4/bash).

it gives this errors while starting up:

```
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
```

I have reason to believe that this may be caused due to my having a space between by account name ("Michael Wilcox").

current path to my home folder on Swan:

```
C:\Users\Michael Wilcox\AppData\Roaming\Swan
```

swan installation:

```
C:\ProgramData\Swan
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Update**: On taking a closer look,
.xsessions-errors reads:

```
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common: line 20: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
/usr/bin/startxfce4: line 111: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
/usr/bin/startxfce4: line 113: [: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc: line 67: test: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc: line 88: test: /home/Michael: binary operator expected
```

xinitrc-common: https://ghostbin.com/paste/7bn7x 
startxfce4: https://ghostbin.com/paste/zfxoe 
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc: https://ghostbin.com/paste/uw4tq 
.bashrc: https://ghostbin.com/paste/4ojjj

Comment: There's an unquoted variable somewhere, possibly in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have updated my queston

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspect, it seems like one of the scripts running each time you open a new shell execute a query on your $HOME which holds spaces which is no good.

xinitrc-common - holds the following line:

```
[ -r $HOME/.profile ] && . $HOME/.profile
```

startxfce4 - holds the following lines:

```
if test "x$XDG_CONFIG_HOME" = "x" 
then 
  BASEDIR="$HOME/.config/xfce4/" 
else 
  BASEDIR="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xfce4" fi
```

/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc - holds the following lines:

```
if test "x$XDG_CONFIG_HOME" = "x" ; then 
  XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/.config 
fi 
[ -d "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME" ] || mkdir "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME"
```

You should quote the $HOME related parameters in those locations as your path containing whitespace.

You should quote those parameters.

e.g. change `$HOME` to be: `"$HOME"`

using "" will cause the shell to identify that "C:\Users\Michael Wilcox\" is one string

Comment: it's not that, please read the updated question.

Comment: @MichaelWilcox - it is indeed a problem which can be solved by using "" , I agree that the problematic scripts are as you mentioned in the updated version of the question. please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `xinitrc-common` does not double quote the expansion of `$HOME` on the line

```
[ -r $HOME/.profile ] && . $HOME/.profile
```

or on the immediately following lines, but it should.

Likewise, `startxfce4` contains unquoted references to `$HOME`, as does the `xinitrc` file.

You will have to modify these so that they use double quotes around the `$HOME` variable expansion (and the expansion of any variables whose values are derived from `$HOME`).

And ideally, if you have the ability to do so, these things, which amounts to bugs, should be reported to the upstream maintainers of the relevant pieces of software.